# Rails Can't remove "\r\n" from record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I've imported some data com CSV files and ended up with a few records containing the string "\r\n" in a column. When exporting to a CSV again, these lines screw up the lines as they insert a new line where it should not...

I've tried to remove with a Rake task, but it seems that  ActiveRecord is not issuing an UPDATE query and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong...

This is what I'm doing:

```
Contact.all.each {|c| 
    next if c.address.nil? || !c.address.include?("\r\n"); 
    c.address.gsub!("\r\n", " - "); 
    c.save; 
}
```

This is the output from a `rails c -s` session:

```
(1.7ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
(0.1ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
(0.0ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
(0.0ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
(0.1ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
(0.1ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
(0.0ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
(0.0ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
```

There is no UPDATE issued...

Any ideas of why it's not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that [`gsub!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-gsub-21) modifies the string in-place:

> **gsub!(pattern, replacement) → str or nil**
>   **gsub!(pattern) {|match| block } → str or nil**
>   **gsub!(pattern) → an_enumerator**
>
> Performs the substitutions of `String#gsub` in place, returning *str*, or `nil` if no substitutions were performed. [...]

[`gsub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-gsub) is quite happy to have a String as its first argument:

> **gsub(pattern, replacement) → new_str** 
>   **gsub(pattern, hash) → new_str**
>   **gsub(pattern) {|match| block } → new_str**
>   **gsub(pattern) → enumerator**
>
> [...] The *pattern* is typically a `Regexp`; if given as a `String`, any regular expression metacharacters it contains will be interpreted literally [...]

So `s.gsub!("\r\n", ' - ')` and `s.gsub!(/\r\n/, ' - ')` will have exactly the same effect.

So what happens when you use `gsub!`? If you do this:

```
c.address.gsub!("\r\n", " - ")
```

you change `c.address` in a way that ActiveRecord won't recognize. For example, try this in the Rails console:

```
> c = Address.find(some_valid_id)
> c.address.gsub!('e', 'x') # Assuming that the address has an 'e' in it of course...
> c.changed?
 => false
> c.address_changed?
 => false
```

So you've changed the address string but ActiveRecord won't know because `c.address` will still be the same String object. Since ActiveRecord doesn't think anything has changed, `c.save` won't do anything.

If you switch to the `gsub` version:

```
c.address = c.address.gsub("\r\n", ' - ')
```

then you will be replacing `c.address` with a whole new String and `c.address_changed?` and `c.changed?` will both be true. Now ActiveRecord will recognize that you've changed `c` and `c.save` (or `c.save!`) will send an UPDATE into your database.

Note that `gsub!` sometimes returning `nil` is wholly irrelevant here, nothing in your code looks at what `gsub!` returns so it doesn't matter what it returns.

---

I'd probably do this sort of thing right inside the database with SQL but the specifics of how you'd do that depend on the underlying database. I cringe whenever my I want to say `Model.all` because I'm used to dealing with big databases where using `all` is just a convenient way to thrash your memory.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to know. Why ActiveRecord was not recognizing that the object had changed. Thanks!

Comment: @Vargas: I think knowing why things are broken is just as important as fixing them.

Answer (score 3):

Use `String.encode(universal_newline: true)` instead gsub.
It converting CRLF and CR to LF

Comment: This does not answer my question at all

Comment: this also does not remove '\n'